# SQL тип данных MONEY не создается

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет. В phpMyadmin во вкладке SQL создаю таблицу.
Нужен столбец с типом MONEY.

CREATE TABLE pc (
`price` money
);
Выдает ошибку. Как я понимаю, такой тип там не поддерживается. Но ведь он существует. В чем проблема?

Comment: *Но ведь он существует.* -- впервые слышу о нём. Откуда вы сделали такой вывод?

Comment: Такой тип данных не существует в мускуле. Постгрес, мс - да. Мускул - нет.

Comment: Decimal/Numeric

Answer (score 0):

Как подсказывает гугл, такой тип данных существует для 
[`transact sql`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql)

Удостоверьтесь что Вы используете именно эту SQL.

Comment: Поправочка: это язык запросов не для MySQL, а для MSSQL (MS=Microsoft).